# Grails - Envers with multiple datasources

Tags: grails, hibernate-envers

I am developing a Grails Application and I have some entities audited with Envers using Lucas Ward's plugin. 
The problem I'm facing is that it only audits the default datasource, I'd like to know if there is a way to change that behaviour.

Thank you very much.

@Gregg By default DataSource I mean the one that is defined just as "dataSource" in DataSource.groovy, the others are defined as"dataSource_something". Lucas Ward's plugin has a class that extends AuditEventListener and takes into account only the default datasource ([link](https://github.com/lucaslward/grails-envers-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/net/lucasward/grails/plugin/AuditEventListenerForDefaultDatasource.groovy)), I tried creating my own AuditEventListener without that condition (and injecting it in resources.groovy) and at least the auditing tables are created in every datasource (originally they were just created in the default one), but changes are not audited in any of them.

Comment: I'm not aware of Envers not working with all DataSources.  And Grails doesn't have a "default" DataSource.  Do you mean the development DataSource?  Maybe you need to provide more details about your problem.